# Java - All permutations and combinations in a given string

Tags: java, logic

I want to get all the permutations and combinations in a given string. I tried the below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProblemStatement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] arr = new String[] {"nokia", "htc", "apple", "samsung","mi"};

        List<String> totalCombinations = getCombinations(arr);

        for(String s : totalCombinations){
            System.out.println(s);
        }


    }

    public static List<String> getCombinations(String[] arr){


        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i <arr.length ; i++){

            if(i > 0){
                String temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[0];
                arr[0] = temp;              
            }
            for(int k=0; k==0 ; k++){

                for(int j=1 ; j<arr.length ; j++){
                    String combination = arr[k] + ":" + arr[j];
                    combinations.add(combination);
                }
            }

        }   
        return combinations;
    }

}

Output:
nokia:htc
nokia:apple
nokia:samsung
nokia:mi
htc:nokia
htc:apple
htc:samsung
htc:mi
apple:nokia
apple:htc
apple:samsung
apple:mi
samsung:nokia
samsung:htc
samsung:apple
samsung:mi
mi:nokia
mi:htc
mi:apple
mi:samsung
```

As per this logic, i see repeated combinations. (Ex : nokia:htc & htc:nokia). I don't need the repeated combinations. Along with that how can i get all the permutations for the given string array.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Along with that how can i get all the permutations for the given string array. What do you mean by "all the permutations for the given string array"?

Comment: @GauravJeswani - Means, For Nokia the below are the list of permutations. the same way for other phones as well. nokia:htc:apple, nokia:htc:samsung, nokia:htc:mi,nokia:apple:samsung,  nokia:apple:mi,nokia:htc:apple:samsung, nokia:htc:apple:samsung:mi

Answer (score 0):

Please try the updated getCombinations(String[] arr) function as below to avoid the duplicate combinations:

```
public static List<String> getCombinations(String[] arr){


        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i <arr.length-1 ; i++){

            for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
                String combination = arr[i] + ":" + arr[j];
                combinations.add(combination);
            }

        }
        return combinations;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for combination part your code should look like this:

```
public static List<String> getCombinations(String[] arr){


    List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i <arr.length ; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < arr.length ; j++) {
                String combination = arr[i] + ":" + arr[j];
                combinations.add(combination);
            }

        }
    return combinations;
}
```

but I don't understand what you want about permutations. Because in permutations, you get duplications and elements that repeats itself obviously. that's the way it is.

Comment: The below are the nokia permutations. nokia:htc:apple, nokia:htc:samsung, nokia:htc:mi,nokia:apple:samsung,  nokia:apple:mi,nokia:htc:apple:samsung, nokia:htc:apple:samsung:mi... The same way for other phones as well